# Exposing Java Enums in the Rhino JavaScript engine

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, enums, rhino

I'm writing a program that incorporates the Rhino Scripting Engine. I would like to be ale to expose a couple of the program's enums, but I can't figure out how to do that, if it's even possible. Is there a way to make a java enum usable in the scripts?

Comment: I suspect the answer to the question is "yes" but I need more information to be sure.

1. By "enums" I assume you mean java.lang.Enum subclasses, in other words, stuff declared with the enum keyword?

2. What do you mean by "expose" them? What do you want the script to see, and what do you want the script to be able to do with the enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to use a java Enum from a script, which will be converted to Java by Rhino?. If this is the case, you could do something like:

- given a java class with an Enum:

  ```
  package com.stackoverflow.example;
  public class Order {

      private String field;
      private By by;

      public enum By {
          ASC, DESC
      }

      public Order(String field, By by) {
          this.field = field;
          this.by = by;
      }
  }
  ```
- and in the script you can do

  ```
  // Importing class with enum
  importClass(Packages.com.stackoverflow.example.Order);

  // Instancing a new Order object using the existing enum in the Order class
  var order = new Order("db_field", Order.By.DESC);
  ```

I hope it helps.